# Restricting access of some roles to some specific pages

Tags: python, flask

Consider:

```py
@bp.route("/products/wishlist", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
@roles_required(
    "ADMIN",
    "CUSTOMER_STORE_MANAGER"
)
def product_wishlist():
    return product_wishlist_page()
```

I have role restrictions like this where each page has some role requirements. I need to restrict some roles, so they could have access to only some specific pages. For example, when
`CUSTOMER_STORE_MANAGER` logins into the webpage, they should only be able to view the `product_wishlist`.

I thought about defining pages for each role and check if they are trying to access to pages which they have authorization.
But is there a more convenient way to do this in Flask?

Answer (score -1):

Filter in the template based on the roles:

```
{% if current_user.role == CUSTOMER_STORE_MANAGER %}
    {# show what this role can view or do #}
{% elif current_user.role == "Admin"%}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

This is simple and rendered on the backend, so it is the same as doing multiple templates with less code.

Comment: This won't do a backend check